# PL SQL Insert index

Tags: oracle, indexing, plsql, records

I need to insert into a table 500.000 records, so the process will take a while. I read about the indexes, that increase the speed of a query, but the question is next: on which parameter should I set the index in order to make the INSERT faster? (the id?).
Thanks.

Edited

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addNewUser(
                            firstName IN VARCHAR2,
                            lastName IN VARCHAR2,
                            email IN VARCHAR2,
                            username IN VARCHAR2,
                            password IN VARCHAR2,
                            job IN VARCHAR2) AS
  v_usersCount NUMBER := 0;
  v_userID NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN 
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_usersCount
  FROM Users;

  v_userID := v_usersCount + 1;

  INSERT INTO Users VALUES(v_userID,firstName,lastName,email,username,password,job);
END addNewUser;
```

and the data is added like this :

```
FOR i IN 1..50000
LOOP
    addNewTask('Task 1', 'Just Starter', 'High', 1, 'This is a description task.', 'Task Comment', '20-08-2015', 1);
END LOOP;
```

Comment: You use indexes for _accessing_ the data faster, not for speeding up inserts. Indexes won't make `INSERT`s faster, but they can make them slower, because the index needs to be updated for each added row.

Comment: Okay, my mistake. Thanks for your response. Do you have an idea why inserting 1000 rows takes about 13 seconds (can the hard-ware of my laptop affect this query?)

Comment: The hardware of the server, memory, resource limits and settings can all have an effect. Are there any triggers on the table? Are you inserting one row at a time (row-by-row, sometimes called 'slow-by-slow') or in batches? Are you committing between inserts? Are you doing any queries or PL/SQL work between inserts? Where are the 500,000 rows-worth of data coming from?

Comment: What does this have to do with PL/SQL? You are not doing some slow row-by-row processing in a cursor, do you?

Comment: Those 500.000 records are added manually through a procedure. I bet the slow part come from my notebook (1.67 GH core 2 duo :) ). Thanks for reponses.

Comment: 'manually through a procedure' doesn't explain what your procedure is doing. Why not show your code?

Comment: I know I can do to insert without a procedure, but this is a homework and I do what I am asked to (this sucks, I know).

Comment: Wrapping each insert into a procedure invocation causes performance problems because of [context switching](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:60122715103602). You could simply use a [`SEQUENCE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm) for populating the id column.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a query for each insertion, which makes it slow.

Try calculate the ID outside your stored and pass it to the procedure, so you don't have to query it in your procedure every time.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(*)...` is one of slowest things you can do in any program. This requires reading every row in the table - so if you're inserting 1000 rows the first time it reads zero rows (fast), next time 1 row (fast), next time 2 rows...and eventually you've executed 1000 queries and read 499500 rows (sum of 0 through 999).

In this case you should use a SEQUENCE to generate non-repeating numbers. I'd rewrite your code as:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE VALUE_SEQ;  -- just take defaults for all parameters

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addNewUser(
                            firstName IN VARCHAR2,
                            lastName IN VARCHAR2,
                            email IN VARCHAR2,
                            username IN VARCHAR2,
                            password IN VARCHAR2,
                            job IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO Users
    VALUES(VALUE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, firstName,lastName,
           email,username,password,job);
END addNewUser;
```